# Hadoop java Got exception: java.net.ConnectException

Tags: java, hadoop

I have installed Hadood-2.6( Distributed mode) on four machines. All daemons are running properly. But when i am running standard teragen example -

```
hadoop jar hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.6.0.jar teragen  10  /input
```

It is giving me following error -

```
hadoop jar /root/exp_testing/hadoop_new/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.6.0.jar teragen  10  /input
15/04/28 05:45:50 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
15/04/28 05:45:51 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at enode1/192.168.1.231:8050
15/04/28 05:45:53 INFO terasort.TeraSort: Generating 10 using 2
15/04/28 05:45:53 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:2
15/04/28 05:45:54 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1430180067597_0001
15/04/28 05:45:54 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1430180067597_0001
15/04/28 05:45:54 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://ubuntu:8088/proxy/application_1430180067597_0001/
15/04/28 05:45:54 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1430180067597_0001
15/04/28 05:46:15 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1430180067597_0001 running in uber mode : false
15/04/28 05:46:15 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
15/04/28 05:46:15 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1430180067597_0001 failed with state FAILED due to: Application application_1430180067597_0001 failed 2 times due to Error launching appattempt_1430180067597_0001_000002. Got exception: java.net.ConnectException: Call From ubuntu/127.0.1.1 to ubuntu:60839 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapWithMessage(NetUtils.java:791)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:731)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1472)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1399)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:232)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy79.startContainers(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.impl.pb.client.ContainerManagementProtocolPBClientImpl.startContainers(ContainerManagementProtocolPBClientImpl.java:96)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.amlauncher.AMLauncher.launch(AMLauncher.java:119)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.amlauncher.AMLauncher.run(AMLauncher.java:254)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:739)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:530)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:494)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupConnection(Client.java:607)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:705)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2800(Client.java:368)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1521)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1438)
    ... 9 more
. Failing the application.
15/04/28 05:46:15 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 0
```

I have two sets( each set contain 4 nodes) of machine same setting is working for other set but i do not  know why am i facing problem with one set ?

/etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
#127.0.1.1      ubuntu
127.0.0.1       ubuntu
#192.168.1.231  ubuntu



192.168.1.231    enode1
192.168.1.232    enode2
192.168.1.233    enode3
192.168.1.234    enode4


# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
~
```

core-site.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<!--
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License. See accompanying LICENSE file.
-->

<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->
<configuration>
<property>
   <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
   <value>hdfs://enode1:9000/</value>
</property>

</configuration>
```

hdfs-site.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<!--
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License. See accompanying LICENSE file.
-->

<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->

<configuration>
<property>
   <name>dfs.replication</name>
   <value>2</value>
 </property>
 <property>
   <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
   <value>file:/home/exp_testing/hdfs/namenode</value>
 </property>
 <property>
   <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
   <value>file:/home/exp_testing/hdfs/datanode</value>
 </property>
</configuration>
```

mapred-site.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<!--
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License. See accompanying LICENSE file.
-->

<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->

<configuration>
        <property>
            <name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.resource.mb</name>
            <value>1536</value>
        </property>
        <property>
            <name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.command-opts</name>
            <value>-Xmx1024m</value>
    </property>
    <property>
       <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>    
       <value>yarn</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>mapreduce.map.cpu.vcores</name>
            <value>1</value>
            <description>The number of virtual cores required for each map task.</description>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>mapreduce.reduce.cpu.vcores</name>
            <value>1</value>
            <description>The number of virtual cores required for each map task.</description>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>mapreduce.map.memory.mb</name>
            <value>1024</value>
            <description>Larger resource limit for maps.</description>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>mapreduce.map.java.opts</name>
            <value>-Xmx400m</value>
            <description>Heap-size for child jvms of maps.</description>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb</name>
                <value>1024</value>
                <description>Larger resource limit for reduces.</description>
        </property>
        <property>
            <name>mapreduce.reduce.java.opts</name>
            <value>-Xmx400m</value>
            <description>Heap-size for child jvms of reduces.</description>
        </property>
        <property>
            <name>mapreduce.jobtracker.address</name>
            <value>enode1:54311</value>
        </property>
</configuration>
```

Yarn-site.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License. See accompanying LICENSE file.
-->
<!-- Site specific YARN configuration properties -->
<configuration>
    <property>
        <description>Whether to enable log aggregation</description>
        <name>yarn.log-aggregation-enable</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb</name>
        <value>10</value>
        <description>Minimum limit of memory to allocate to each container request at the Resource Manager.</description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb</name>
        <value>6144</value>
        <description>Maximum limit of memory to allocate to each container request at the Resource Manager.</description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-vcores</name>
        <value>1</value>
        <description>The minimum allocation for every container request at the RM, in terms of virtual CPU cores. Requests lower than this                    won't take effect, and the specified value will get allocated the minimum.</description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-vcores</name>
        <value>32</value>
        <description>The maximum allocation for every container request at the RM, in terms of virtual CPU cores. Requests higher than this                       won't take effect, and will get capped to this value.</description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
        <value>6144</value>
        <description>Physical memory, in MB, to be made available to running containers</description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores</name>
        <value>8</value>
        <description>Number of CPU cores that can be allocated for containers.</description>
    </property>
    <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
    <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
     </property>
     <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
     </property>
     <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>
        <value>enode1:8025</value>
        <description>The hostname of the RM.</description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
        <value>enode1:8030</value>
        <description>The hostname of the RM.</description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
        <value>enode1:8050</value>
        <description>The hostname of the RM.</description>
    </property>

</configuration>
```

Result of hadoop fs -ls /

```
root@ubuntu:~/exp_testing/mysrc# hadoop fs -ls /
15/04/29 00:43:57 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Found 2 items
drwxr-xr-x   - root supergroup          0 2015-04-29 00:43 /input
drwx------   - root supergroup          0 2015-04-29 00:43 /tmp
```

@sandeep007734 solution is working for my new set of cluster, I am convinced by his solution but the in older set of cluster i have commented
following line in /etc/hosts and it is working fine

#127.0.1.1      ubuntu

I do not know why is this happening ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem is the Hostname configuration. If you are using custom hostnames (which are defined only in you /etc/hosts file and not in the dns) then the hadoop can behave in strange ways sometime.

You are using names enode1, enode2 etc as the name of your nodes.

But in the error that you have posted it is showing:

```
15/04/28 05:45:54 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://ubuntu:8088/proxy/application_1430180067597_0001/
```

Here it is saying that to track the job, the url is http://ubuntu...
It means hadoop is picking up the hostname of the system to do its operations.

Now one of the obvious solution will be go in the /etc/hosts file and add the entry( in each of the node, including master). For example on enode1

```
192.168.1.231 ubuntu
```

This will work fine when you try to format the namenode and start the cluster.

But if you try to run some job, you wil get into trouble, because the slave will try to connect the resource manager using the address

```
ubuntu/192.168.1.231
```

which means, if you are not able to resolve the ubuntu hostname, use the IP. But the slave is able to resolve the IP which is mapped to its own IP.

For example, when the slave running on the machine enode2 tries to connect to the Resource Manager, it uses **ubuntu/192.168.1.231**. The ubuntu hostname gets resolved to **192.168.1.232** because you just defined this in your /etc/hosts file.

During the execution of the job, in logs you should be able to see the erros:

```
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server
```

It really tries to connect to Resource Manager for a long time and **that is why you teragen job is taking so long to execute**. Because the MAP task that are scheduled on the slaves, tries a long time to connect to Resource Manager and eventually fails. Only those MAP tasks, which are scheduled on the master node (as you are using your master also as a slave) will succeed (because the  ubuntu correctly resolved the Resource Manager IP on the master node only).

The solution to this problem is.

1. Stop the Hadoop Cluster
2. Edit the file /etc/hostname on each of the machines
   For example on the machine enode1

From:

```
ubuntu
```

To:

```
enode1
```

enode2, enode3 on the corresponding machines.

3. Remove the entry for ubuntu in the /etc/hosts file.
4. Reboot
5. Make sure the hostname is changed by the command

   hostname
6. Format the Namdenode
7. Start the cluster and run that teragen again. It should run fine.

Answer (score 0):

> Got exception: java.net.ConnectException: Call From ubuntu/**127.0.1.1** to ubuntu:60839 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

This error mostly occurs due to loopback problems. To rectify this issue, change `127.0.1.1` to `127.0.0.1` in `etc/hosts` file. Now, restart the hadoop processes and try running the example. It should work.

Comment: Same problem is coming. I have also tried actual static IP of my machine in place of 127.0.1.1.

Comment: Post your `/etc/hosts`, `core-site.xml`, `hdfs-site.xml` and `mapred-site.xml` files.

Comment: I forgot to tell one thing when i am replacing 127.0.1.1 with 127.0.0.1. It is not showing any error but it is not showing any progress on console( means it is hanging for very long time ).

Comment: What does `hadoop fs -ls /` results?

Comment: problem seems to be the container creation! can you please post the yarn-site.xml also.

Comment: Result of hadoop fs -ls /                                                                                                          drwxr-xr-x   - root supergroup          0 2015-04-29 00:43 /input
drwx------   - root supergroup           0 2015-04-29 00:43 /tmp

Comment: It took 2:30 hour for generating result when i replaced 127.0.1.1 with 127.0.0.1.

Comment: HDFS `/input` directory is owned by root user. It must be owned by hadoop user. Change it using `hadoop fs -chown -R hadoopuser:supergroup /input`. Did you run hadoop example as hadoop user?

Answer (score 0):

try to remove these lines from `/etc/hosts` and disable you ipv6 if you are not using it :

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       ubuntu
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
~
```

One problem with IPv6 is that using 0.0.0.0 for the various networking-related Hadoop configuration options will result in Hadoop binding to the IPv6 addresses.

So if you are not using IPv6, it’s better to disable it because it can cause problems while running Hadoop.

To disable IPv6, open `/etc/sysctl.conf` in the editor of your choice and add the following lines to the end of the file:

```
# disable ipv6
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem and Finally and Luckily i solve it . The problem is host!!!!.

just 
su root

hostname master on master node

hostname slave on slave node

restart the cluster.

it's ok

...........................................................

here what it looks like on my machines.

(1)Here is my problem:

```
miaofu@miaofu-Virtual-Machine:~/hadoop-2.6.4/etc/hadoop$ hadoop jar ../../share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.6.4.jar wordcount /in /out2
16/09/17 15:41:14 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at master/192.168.202.104:8032
16/09/17 15:41:17 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 9
16/09/17 15:41:17 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:9
16/09/17 15:41:17 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1474096034614_0002
16/09/17 15:41:18 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1474096034614_0002
16/09/17 15:41:18 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://master:8088/proxy/application_1474096034614_0002/
16/09/17 15:41:18 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1474096034614_0002
16/09/17 15:41:26 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1474096034614_0002 running in uber mode : false
16/09/17 15:41:26 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
16/09/17 15:41:39 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 11% reduce 0%
16/09/17 15:41:40 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 22% reduce 0%
16/09/17 15:41:41 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 67% reduce 0%
16/09/17 15:41:54 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 67% reduce 22%
16/09/17 15:44:29 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1474096034614_0002_m_000006_0, Status : FAILED
Container launch failed for container_1474096034614_0002_01_000008 : java.net.ConnectException: Call From miaofu-Virtual-Machine/127.0.0.1 to localhost:57019 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: 拒绝连接; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor32.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapWithMessage(NetUtils.java:791)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:731)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1473)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1400)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:232)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy36.startContainers(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.impl.pb.client.ContainerManagementProtocolPBClientImpl.startContainers(ContainerManagementProtocolPBClientImpl.java:96)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:187)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy37.startContainers(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.launcher.ContainerLauncherImpl$Container.launch(ContainerLauncherImpl.java:151)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.launcher.ContainerLauncherImpl$EventProcessor.run(ContainerLauncherImpl.java:369)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

(2) here is my configuration:
/etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1 miaofu-Virtual-Machine
192.168.202.104 master
192.168.202.31 slave01
192.168.202.105 slave02
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

(3) set hostname 
on master node:

```
root@miaofu-Virtual-Machine:/home/miaofu# vi /etc/hostname 
root@miaofu-Virtual-Machine:/home/miaofu# hostname
miaofu-Virtual-Machine
root@miaofu-Virtual-Machine:/home/miaofu# hostname master
root@miaofu-Virtual-Machine:/home/miaofu# hostname
master
```

on slave:

```
miaofu@miaofu-Virtual-Machine:~$ su root
密码： 
^Z
[3]+  已停止               su root
miaofu@miaofu-Virtual-Machine:~$ sudo passwd root
[sudo] password for miaofu: 
输入新的 UNIX 密码： 
重新输入新的 UNIX 密码： 
passwd：已成功更新密码
miaofu@miaofu-Virtual-Machine:~$ hostname slave02
hostname: you must be root to change the host name
miaofu@miaofu-Virtual-Machine:~$ su root
密码： 
root@miaofu-Virtual-Machine:/home/miaofu# 
root@miaofu-Virtual-Machine:/home/miaofu# 
root@miaofu-Virtual-Machine:/home/miaofu# 
root@miaofu-Virtual-Machine:/home/miaofu# hostname slave02
root@miaofu-Virtual-Machine:/home/miaofu# hostname 
slave02
```

(4) restart the cluster

```
stop-yarn.sh
stop-dfs.sh
cd
rm -r hadoop-2.6.4/tmp/*

hadoop namenode -format
start-dfs.sh
start-yarn.sh
```

(5) just run the wordcount

```
miaofu@miaofu-Virtual-Machine:~$ hadoop fs -mkdir /in
miaofu@miaofu-Virtual-Machine:~$ vi retry.sh 
miaofu@miaofu-Virtual-Machine:~$ hadoop fs -put etc/hadoop/*.xml /in
put: `etc/hadoop/*.xml': No such file or directory
miaofu@miaofu-Virtual-Machine:~$ hadoop fs -put hadoop-2.6.4/etc/hadoop/*.xml /in
jpmiaofu@miaofu-Virtual-Machine:~$ jps
61591 Jps
60601 ResourceManager
60297 SecondaryNameNode
60732 NodeManager
60092 DataNode
59927 NameNode
miaofu@miaofu-Virtual-Machine:~$ hadoop jar hadoop-2.6.4/
bin/         etc/         include/     lib/         LICENSE.txt  NOTICE.txt   sbin/        tmp/         
conf.sh      home/        input/       libexec/     logs/        README.txt   share/       
miaofu@miaofu-Virtual-Machine:~$ hadoop jar hadoop-2.6.4/share/
doc/    hadoop/ 
miaofu@miaofu-Virtual-Machine:~$ hadoop jar hadoop-2.6.4/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.6.4.jar wordcount /in /out
^Z
[1]+  已停止               hadoop jar hadoop-2.6.4/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.6.4.jar wordcount /in /out
miaofu@miaofu-Virtual-Machine:~$ hadoop jar hadoop-2.6.4/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.6.4.jar wordcount /in /out3
16/09/17 16:46:24 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at master/192.168.202.104:8032
16/09/17 16:46:25 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 9
16/09/17 16:46:25 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:9
16/09/17 16:46:26 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1474101888060_0001
16/09/17 16:46:26 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1474101888060_0001
16/09/17 16:46:26 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://master:8088/proxy/application_1474101888060_0001/
16/09/17 16:46:26 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1474101888060_0001
16/09/17 16:46:35 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1474101888060_0001 running in uber mode : false
16/09/17 16:46:35 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
16/09/17 16:46:44 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 22% reduce 0%
16/09/17 16:46:45 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 33% reduce 0%
16/09/17 16:46:48 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 67% reduce 0%
16/09/17 16:46:49 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
16/09/17 16:46:51 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 100%
16/09/17 16:46:52 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1474101888060_0001 completed successfully
16/09/17 16:46:52 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 50
    File System Counters
        FILE: Number of bytes read=21875
        FILE: Number of bytes written=1110853
        FILE: Number of read operations=0
        FILE: Number of large read operations=0
        FILE: Number of write operations=0
        HDFS: Number of bytes read=28532
        HDFS: Number of bytes written=10579
        HDFS: Number of read operations=30
        HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
        HDFS: Number of write operations=2
    Job Counters 
        Killed map tasks=1
        Launched map tasks=9
        Launched reduce tasks=1
        Data-local map tasks=9
        Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=84614
        Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=4042
        Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=84614
        Total time spent by all reduce tasks (ms)=4042
        Total vcore-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=84614
        Total vcore-milliseconds taken by all reduce tasks=4042
        Total megabyte-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=86644736
        Total megabyte-milliseconds taken by all reduce tasks=4139008
    Map-Reduce Framework
        Map input records=796
        Map output records=2887
        Map output bytes=36776
        Map output materialized bytes=21923
        Input split bytes=915
        Combine input records=2887
        Combine output records=1265
        Reduce input groups=606
        Reduce shuffle bytes=21923
        Reduce input records=1265
        Reduce output records=606
        Spilled Records=2530
        Shuffled Maps =9
        Failed Shuffles=0
        Merged Map outputs=9
        GC time elapsed (ms)=590
        CPU time spent (ms)=6470
        Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=2690990080
        Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=8380964864
        Total committed heap usage (bytes)=1966604288
    Shuffle Errors
        BAD_ID=0
        CONNECTION=0
        IO_ERROR=0
        WRONG_LENGTH=0
        WRONG_MAP=0
        WRONG_REDUCE=0
    File Input Format Counters 
        Bytes Read=27617
    File Output Format Counters 
        Bytes Written=10579
```

contact me if you have problem 13347217145@163.com